# Polymer Gestures tracking not working on touch devices

Tags: polymer

I have created a Polymer application that is listening for the `trackstart`, `track` and `trackend` events. It uses these events allow a SVG element to be dragged around. The events work correctly for desktop, however, for my Galaxy Nexus and Nexus 10 the events are not fired.

I have looked at the source code in the polymer-gestures project and it seems like the events are implemented using the `touchstart`, etc events in `touch.js`.

I'm using version `0.3.1` of `platform.js` which I assume has the `polymer-gestures` `0.3.1` in it.

How can I get the `trackstart`, `track` and `trackend` (also `hold` would be nice too) events working on my touchscreen devices?

Comment: Hmm, this could be that my bower is using polymer `0.2.3` which pulls in platform `0.2.3`.

Comment: I've cloned `master` from github and still can't get any `track*` events through.

Comment: The test page for `polymer-gestures` is working. I must be doing something in my web component to stop them occuring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it'll be the `touch-action:none` CSS value that is needed to make sure the events are handled with JavaScript.

Comment: _Note:_ it seems that Chrome doesn't recognise `touch-action` in CSS but does as an attribute to the HTML element.

Comment: The attribute is used by polymer-gestures to either set touch-action if supported, or set a few flags in the touch event handler to allow or disallow scrolling.